Flutter Xcode 16 undefined symbols error?
My app runs ok with Xcode 15.4, but failed with Xcode 16. Not sure what happened. Below is the log.
ld: warning: no platform load command found in '[project-path]/ios/Pods/MLKitTextRecognitionCommon/Frameworks/MLKitTextRecognitionCommon.framework/MLKitTextRecognitionCommon', assuming: iOS
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'CoreAudioTypes': framework 'CoreAudioTypes' not found
ld: warning: Could not parse or use implicit file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUICore.framework/SwiftUICore.tbd': cannot link directly with 'SwiftUICore' because product being built is not an allowed client of it
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_swiftoverride_class_getSuperclass(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*)", referenced from:
      swift::swift50override_conformsToProtocol(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetWitnessTable<swift::InProcess> const* (*)(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*)) in libswiftCompatibility50.a[arm64][6](ProtocolConformance.cpp.o)
  "swift::swift51override_conformsToSwiftProtocol(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*, __swift::__runtime::llvm::StringRef, swift::TargetProtocolConformanceDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const* (*)(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*, __swift::__runtime::llvm::StringRef))", referenced from:
      _Swift50Overrides in libswiftCompatibility50.a[arm64][7](Overrides.cpp.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Thank you.

I believe you tried to regenerate the Xcode project, clean & rebuild AFTER you updated the Xcode version, right?

@Raptor Oh, I haven't tried regenerating the Xcode project. It's also quite complicated because of the flavors. But can you tell me what's the difference? I will go for it if that's the way.

from time to time, the Xcode project might get corrupted. As long as you are using Flutter to develop your app, your Xcode project can always be regenerated via flutter create -i swift . inside your project folder. Remember to close Xcode first.

The reason is that some pods use an incompatible Swift version. A workaround is to add flag to "Other Linker Flags". One of these 2 below, or both:
-lswiftCompatibility50

-lswiftCompatibility51

The correct fix is to update pubs and pods, then no pod uses an incompatible Swift version.
